# How to resolve Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null for tinymce.4.2.7.min.js?

Tags: reactjs, tinymce

I am using `react-tinymce 0.2.3` and tinymce 4.2.7.
as per below code in `handleEditorChange`, after call of **e.target.getContent()** I am getting error

> tinymce.4.2.7.min.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null

I tried to put e.target.getContent() in jQuery's ready function but no success.

I am using react 0.13.3.

```
<TinyMCE config={...} content={html} onBlur={this.handleEditorChange} />
```

Comment: You should try draftjs from facebook. It is a good alternative to tinymce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The document's `ready()` functionality does not ensure that TinyMCE is initialized and ready for interaction.  There is an `init()` function that you can add to your TinyMCE configuration that will tell you when the editor itself is initialized and ready for interaction.  You can put the code in your TinyMCE init:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '.editor',
    ....
    setup: function (editor) {
      editor.on('init', function () {
         this.setContent('Using the on init stuff!');
    });
});
```

Comment: let me try @michale-fromin

Comment: Thanks @michale-fromin issue in react-tinymce 0.2.3 on calling of https://github.com/instructure-react/react-tinymce/blob/51906f8e261453207cf2796c6c59f5ee1a434f29/lib/components/TinyMCE.js#L50 `this._init` it have two parameter and here it has been called only one, and making content `undefiend`.

Comment: @Michael Fromin I am also facing same issue in tinymce.js, after upgrade chrome browser latest version. Tinymce version-4.3.11 chrome - Version 85.0.4183.83 (Official Build) (64-bit) and extjs framework.
Note:Working fine in lower version of chrome.

Comment: Michael's approach is not working with TinyMCE 4.3.13 since upgrading Chrome to version 86.0.4240.111 similar to @mvm experience. Any idea?